# AnyLogic: How to check the availability of a process depending on the time and a probability?

Tags: java, anylogic

I need a way to check the availability of a delay block depending on the current time in the model. In the end I want to check for a suitable time window to perform a process.

For this I have a table (MS Excel) with the month, the day, the hour and an associated probability (e.g. 8; 5; 2; 0,9134 represents a probability of 91,34 % at 2 AM on the 5th of august).

Now I want to check the time window as if I would toss a coin with the given probability.

Since the time window is longer than 1 hour I need to check the probability in the next hour(s) too.

#### Example:

My process (delay block) has a delay of 5 hours. When the agent enters I want to "toss a coin" for the first, second, third, fourth and fifth hour since the time stamps have different probabilitys. When all five tosses are successful, the agent enters the process and the process is performed.

I hope I made my point clear enough. I tried to implement an excelFile but I have no clue how to proceed further.

Thank you in advance!

Edit: I'm using the Personal Learning Edition.

Comment: why do you want to do that, what are you modelling? I suspect this is based on actual historic data and you try to mimic historic behavior? If so, you shouldn't do it like this...

Comment: You are right. I want to check If a lifting process with a crane is restricted by the weather (wind velocity) based on a set of historical weather data. I used the weibull distribution via excel to determine the chance that the wind velocity is below the limit value of the process. This was my approach but I am open for recommendations.

Comment: You will need to code this yourself but you should do it in one single "SelectOutput" block ahead of the delay. Make the agent check how long it would need the crane for and then write a function that returns true or false. Then for each upcoming hour, use the the function "randomTrue(x)" where x is the probability of that hour.